# Why doesn't iPython see readline?

Tags: python, macports, readline

I am trying to compare/contrast various python tools and I would like ipython in the mix, but when I run ipython I get the readline warning even though readline is installed on my mac:

> WARNING: Readline services not available on this platform.
> WARNING: The auto-indent feature requires the readline library

After reading Stack Overflow's [installing-ipython-with-readline-on-the-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726449/installing-ipython-with-readline-on-the-mac), I checked my port installed and discovered that py26-ipython was not among my installed ports.  Installing this did not fix my problem, nor does it answer my question.  Are there perhaps different python paths for different utilities?  Something else?  Any advice is much appreciated.

Here are the original symptoms:

1. ipython is installed on my mac in my python directory - must have come with one of the macports installed packages - and launched just fine, but gave the readline warning mentioned above
2. I checked and readline is among the port installed programs; furthermore, "import readline" is successful in interactive python and in spyder
3. easy_install readline indicated that "readline 6.1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth"
4. readline is not on my path (and I don't know that it should be), but the headers can be found in /opt/local/include/readline/
5. I have removed the the full listing of installed ports (prior to implementing the stack overflow fix) because the answer didn't seem to need them, but can add them back if I learn a way to show/hide or otherwise minimize real estate

Here are the additional data points from after installing ipython with macports.

1. ## 1-#3 above are still true.
2. I have removed the additionally installed ports because the answer didn't seem to need them, but can add them back if I learn a way to show/hide or otherwise minimize real estate

After seeing the StackOverflow Q&A, I decided to follow up and this seems like a better forum for this question.

Comment: I'ld check with @Dennis Williamson...he's a python ninja....check his stackoverflow posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *…but when I run ipython…*

Where was this ipython from since it existed before you installed the `py26-ipython` port. Also, after you installed the MacPorts ipython, be sure you are running `/opt/local/bin/ipython-2.6`.

> *ipython is installed on my mac in my python directory…*

Is this at `/usr/bin/`, `/opt/local/bin`, or somewhere else?

All I can say is be sure you're running the right ipython. And don't use `easy_install` to install packages for MacPorts unless you change the prefix to something other than `/opt/local` (such as `~/local`). Otherwise it can conflict with already available ports.

Comment: I'm not sure where it came from, but ipython was pointed to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipython`.  When I run `/opt/local/bin/ipython-2.6`, this works.  Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I should add for others running down this answer that I created a symbolic link in /opt/local/bin titled ipython and pointed to ipython-2.6 - since /opt/local/bin comes before the python directories on my path, this is now what is found.